# Ansible Python API - how to get variables defined in vars_files, host_vars, group_vars

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

I am trying to pull `variables` from all possible locations using `Python API`

In my playbook `test_play.yml` I have..

```
---
hosts: abc.com
gather_facts: no

roles:
  - my_roles

vars_files:
  - var/var.yml    

tasks:   
  .....
  .....
```

file structure -

```
test_play.yml
roles
  - my_roles
    -- defaults
vars
  - var.yml
hosts
  - DEV
    -- hosts
    -- group_vars
       --- all.yml
```

My code --

```
host_file = path_to_host_file
play_path = path_to_playbook

inventory = InventoryManager(loader=DataLoader(), source=[host_file])
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=DataLoader(), inventory=inventory)

pb = Playbook.load(play_path, variable_manager, DataLoader())
play = pb.get_plays()

# here I get one play, which is fine
all_vars = variable_manager.get_vars(play=plays[0])
```

in `all_vars`, I am getting variables defined in `inventory file, rules` only. But the variables defined in `var.yml, group_vars/all.yml` are missing. How to get them?

Comment: I am having the same issue; any ideas?

Comment: Any good answer?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to:

```py
variable_manager.get_vars(host=inventory.get_host("hostname"))
```

It is sad that Ansible does not provide a better documentation for their API.